# Sending mail when error occurrs

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I use log4net for logging errors. Logging to files works, now I want an error also to be sent by mail. But I can't get it to work. Here is my config file:

```
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <to value="test@gmail.com" />
  <from value="test@gmail.com" />
  <subject value="Test - Error" />
  <smtpHost value="smtp.gmail.com" />
  <authentication value="Basic" />
  <port value="587" />
  <username value="MyUsername" />
  <password value="MyPassword" />
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <lossy value="true" />
  <threshold value="ERROR"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="[%date{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff}] %level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
    <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender" />
</root>
```

I saw that someone is using `<EnableSsl value="true" />` also but when I copy it inside appender tag it says that it is invalid element. By the way when I send other emails through C# code I set `EnableSsl` to true.

Comment: What version of log4net are you using?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev 2.0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to debug what is going on is to enable log4net internal logging:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

This will print to the console and System.Diagnostics.Trace system any potential issues with your appender configuration. What I can see as issues is that you have specified `lossy` but didn't add an evaluator:

```
<lossy value="true" />
<evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator,log4net">
    <threshold value="ERROR" />
</evaluator>
```

Basically you need to put the `<threshold>` setting that you currently have inside the evaluator section.

Also you should add the `<EnableSsl value="true" />` switch because this is required by gmail.

Another thing to verify is that gmail isn't blocking the address from which you are trying to send the email. Log into your gmail account and look if there are some emails indicating blocked activity.

Comment: That part with lossy and evaluator was the problem.